# How can I check if a number is a multiple of the input - PHP

Tags: php, math, multiplication

What I am trying to build is a function that takes an input number and checks if the following number is a multiple of that number.

```
function checkIfMult($input,$toBeChecked){
   // some logic
}
```

example:

```
checkIfMult(2,4) // true
checkIfMult(2,6) // true
checkIfMult(2,7) // false

checkIfMult(3,6) // true
checkIfMult(3,9) // true
checkIfMult(3,10) // false
```

My first instinct was to use arrays

```
$tableOf2 = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
```

But then a call like this would be highly unpractical:

```
checkIfMult(6,34234215)
```

How can I check to see if something is a multiple of the input?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Use the [%](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator.

The Modulo operator divides the numbers and returns the remainder.

In math, a multiple means that the remainder equals 0.

```
function checkIfMult($input,$toBeChecked){
   return $toBeChecked % $input === 0; 
}
```

```js
function checkIfMult($input, $toBeChecked){
   console.log('checkIfMult(' + $input +',' + $toBeChecked + ')', $toBeChecked % $input === 0);
   return $toBeChecked % $input === 0;
}

checkIfMult(2,4) // true
checkIfMult(2,6) // true
checkIfMult(2,7) // false

checkIfMult(3,6) // true
checkIfMult(3,9) // true
checkIfMult(3,10) // false
```

Comment: –1; Mixing javascript with php is evil ;(

Answer (score 3):

You can use the modulus operator, if the result is 0 then the function should return true. The modulus operator (**%**) performs a division and returns the remainder.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 2):

You can modulo `%` Like:

> In computing, the `modulo` operation finds the remainder after division
>   of one number by another (sometimes called modulus).

```
function checkIfMult($input,$toBeChecked){
   return !( $toBeChecked % $input );
}
```

This follow the result

```
echo "<br />" . checkIfMult(2,4); // true
echo "<br />" . checkIfMult(2,6); // true
echo "<br />" . checkIfMult(2,7); // false

echo "<br />" . checkIfMult(3,6); // true
echo "<br />" . checkIfMult(3,9); // true
echo "<br />" . checkIfMult(3,10); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, You can also divide the $tobechecked by $input and check if there is a remainder by using the floor function.

```
if(is_int($result))
 { echo "It is a multiple";
    }
 else
 { echo "It isn't a multiple"; }
```

Comment: Like the idea but it can be simplified even more. What you actually are checking is if the result is an integer. So `if(is_int($result))`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use % operator**

```
function check($a,$b){
   if($b % $a > 0){
     return 0;
   }
   else{
    return 1;
   }
}
```